# php redirect immediately and also continue execution which dont send data

Tags: php, redirect

I need to execute a bunch of functions that consume nearly 50 seconds to complete. But i want redirect to page after execution few function itself and also continue further execution.

The below function execute on form submit as in `process.php // it wont echo anything`

```
// all function in serprate process page.
func1
func2
func3
// After above 3 function i need to php redirect to redirect now immediately example.com
func4
func5
func6
```

I tried using php header but it won't immediately redirecting.

```
header("Location:http://www.example.com");
```

If I use `exit();` it will redirect but not process function 4,5 and 6.

what i need is any way to redirect immediately after first 3 functions and continue execution.

Comment: Why are you needing to do this?

Comment: split this into two different requests

Comment: Those function took 50secs in processing as it use external api, i am not sure no visitor will wait that long on a blank page.

Comment: I bet you're looking for something like [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php), but I'd make sure to consider a different route entirely, like running the second set of functions on a different page.

Comment: Try to redesign it so those functions can be called in a cron or something not user related if they take so long.

Comment: Its not ignore_user_abort. What i need is to run last three function in background in same block.

Comment: So, you might use php `exec()`function. There's an interesting comment on this page : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php#86329

Comment: @Brewal it seems the answer can you explain it well for above problem . execInBackground($cmd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to split your `process.php` in two files : `process.php` and `process_more.php` (i.e.). Assuming your are under a unix os server :

Code for `process.php` :

```
// code to execute before redirect
func1();
func2();
func3();
// code to execute after redirect in background
// you can pass some parameters
$command = "php -f /path/to/process_more.php param1 param2"
exec($command . " > /dev/null &"); 
header('Location: http://dn.tld/');
exit();
```

See more to use parameters with **[$argv](http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.argv.php)** variable, and be careful to prevent the user for injecting another command within the parameters

Code for `process_more.php` :

```
func2();
func3();
func4();
```

Not that you won't be able to access `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables. You need to pass any variable you want within the call command.

Comment: I just need to pass two strings as parameter to that file can i simply pass `$command = "php -f /path/to/process_more.php string1 string2"`

Comment: Yes, no problem. But be careful, if the string comes from `$_GET` or `$_POST` in the `process.php`, the user could type something like `&& rm -rf *` in the field, you know what it can do. In this case, you will need to make sure the string has no space, etc...

Comment: That's fine , how can i retrive those arguments `$string1=$agrv[1]; $string2=$argv[2]; ` is that correct i tried buts its not working. The `process-more.php` looks as `<?php $string1=$agrv[1]; $string2=$argv[2]; func4(); func5(); func6(); ?>` . Is it correct, but not working.

Comment: It's `$argv` not `$agrv`. Dump the variable : `var_dump($argv)`

Comment: Sorry that's ok , but can i send url as `$command = "php -f /path/to/process_more.php http://www.example.com example.com"` as arguments

Comment: There might be issues with some char, I don't really know for sure. Test it. You can add double quotes around your string within the command : `$command = 'php -f /path/to/process_more.php "http://www.url.com/" "example.com"'`

Answer (score 3):

On paper, you can achieve this by combining flush() and ignore_user_abort():

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
do_stuff();
send_redirect();
flush();
do_more_stuff();
```

Manual pages:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Note the known caveats: some browsers (old IEs in particular, and possibly new ones) want a minimum amount of bytes received before processing what you send them, so you might end up needing to toss in some long string in an html comment for it to work as expected.

In practice, the more conventional approach is to register a cron job task in some table, and have a cron.php file take care of pending tasks in a completely separate (and independent) request.

A less conventional approach is also highlighted in the comments: issue a shell command or something to that order — be very wary of sanitizing input if you do that.

---

Adding this for reference (see comments below):

```
<!-- IE bug fix: pad the page with enough characters such that it is greater than 512 bytes, even after gzip compression abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz11223344556677889900abacbcbdcdcededfefegfgfhghgihihjijikjkjlklkmlmlnmnmononpopoqpqprqrqsrsrtstsubcbcdcdedefefgfabcadefbghicjkldmnoepqrfstugvwxhyz1i234j567k890laabmbccnddeoeffpgghqhiirjjksklltmmnunoovppqwqrrxsstytuuzvvw0wxx1yyz2z113223434455666777889890091abc2def3ghi4jkl5mno6pqr7stu8vwx9yz11aab2bcc3dd4ee5ff6gg7hh8ii9j0jk1kl2lmm3nnoo4p5pq6qrr7ss8tt9uuvv0wwx1x2yyzz13aba4cbcb5dcdc6dedfef8egf9gfh0ghg1ihi2hji3jik4jkj5lkl6kml7mln8mnm9ono
—>
```

References:

- http://www.clintharris.net/2009/ie-512-byte-error-pages-and-wordpress/
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8942
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11289

(Actually applies only for http errors, after re-going through it.)

Comment: It's not about the user_abort or user closing connection. Its entirely about redirecting immediately in php or executing few functions in background

Comment: @subhash: flush() sends headers and whatever content there currently is.

Comment: I don't want send any data , i want redirect at the current position after `func3();` and also continue the execution of func 4,5 and 6 in background

Comment: @subhash: you actually want to send headers, which is data in its own right. But as noted, some browsers will ignore that data until it reaches a certain size. Some browsers wait for a certain amount of data before beginning to process anything that got sent, and a handful of them (old IEs in particular) expect a certain amount of *gzipped* data before proceeding when you gzip your pages before sending them. For this reason, you'd want to toss in a nonsensical uncompressible string as an html comment in addition to the header — just to make sure the header is always processed without delay.

Comment: **I don't Want to Send any Data**. Acually i want to process 5 functions in background , Brewal has explained exec() function but can you explain it that will be help.

Comment: Sigh... Again: The header/location ***IS*** data. It is a not a magical unicorn that miraculously end up in your browser. It can be ***flushed*** to the browser (that is, force-sent) so that the latter receives it and processes it in advance. ***\*\*\*BUT\*\*\**** be wary that some browsers *ignore* this data until they receive a large enough amount of it. For this reason, you ***must*** also send additional data, else the redirect won't occur until you close connection -- i.e. minutes later. More clear?

Comment: sorry for understanding late now only i understand , thank you that's works even better.

Comment: Hey i tried flush() but the when i send header redirect it work redirect as you said. Can help me how to redirect or how much data need to send.

Comment: If memory serves, it needed to be 512k of data when we ran into this issue with WordPress, but with a twist: old IEs want 512k of *compressed* data when the latter is gzipped, so we eventually opted to send a body consisting of an html comment with 512k of incompressible string data within it. I'm at a loss to locate the relevant code in the WP code base, however. But that would be the gist of it.

Comment: At the end of the day, though, I'd stress that these ugly caveats make it unwieldy and probably not worthwhile. It is ***much*** better to register some kind of cron task in your script, and to have a separate process take things over from there. (Fire it using ajax or an actual cron. See the WordPress cron, or that of other similar projects, for ideas on how to implement it.)

Comment: Errata: was meant `512 bytes`, not `512k bytes`. And, for a rather well designed cron handler, I vaguely recall there was one in the Habari project.

Comment: @subhash: I found the needed string and reference while looking for something else in the WP code base. Answer updated. (Turns out it only applies for error pages, though.)